# How to change data array to be object using javascript?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have data like this `{"black":["/file/d60f198e-dde5-4e5e-b2ab-1ee10c96a027.png"]}`

how to change data to be `"black" : "/file/d60f198e-dde5-4e5e-b2ab-1ee10c96a027.png"` ? I'm using javascript. Thanks advance

Comment: `obj.black = obj.black[0]`. That's it!

Answer (score 2):

A generic solution would be something like:

```
var data = {
   black: ['abc'],
   red: ['xyz']
}

var result = _.mapObject(data, _.first)
```

which would give you:

```
{
    black: 'abc',
    red: 'xyz'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set that property to be the value of the array:

```
var original = {"black":["/file/d60f198e-dde5-4e5e-b2ab-1ee10c96a027.png"]}
original.black = original.black[0]
```