# How to convert arrray to be string url using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js, lodash

I'm beginner of AngularJS, and now I'm building simple app.

I have some HTML code like this

```
<table class="table" ng-repeat="(attr, assets) in customize.product.attributes">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">{{attr}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="asset in assets">
        <td>
            {{asset}}
        </td>
        <td>
                <file-uploader class="form-control"
                    image-width="{{galleryConfigs.width}}"
                    image-height="{{galleryConfigs.height}}"
                    image-crop-width="{{galleryConfigs.width}}"
                    image-crop-height="{{galleryConfigs.height}}"
                    max-size="5000"
                    allowed-extensions="png,jpeg,jpg"
                    result-model="customize.assets[attr][asset]">
                </file-uploader>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And this is my code JS

```
$scope.create = function(published){
        var published = published || false,
            customize = angular.copy($scope.customize);

        if(published)
            customize.published = true;

        dataProvider.Customize.save(customize).$promise
        .then(function(_customize){
            if(!_customize) throw 'Error System';

            toast.create({content:'Succes', className:'success'});
            $state.go('pos.product.customize.show',{customizeId:_customize.id});
        }).catch(function (error){
            $log.error(error);
        });
    };
```

When I push the data turns out the data stored as shown below like that

```
"assets" : {
    "part 1" : {
        "black" : [ 
            "/file/c36a3297-11bb-4028-8cb7-d750b98436ec.png", 
            "/file/4a6ec1ed-c3b1-48f9-84c0-61dd0f6da08a.png", 
            "/file/c66ac97a-18be-4e79-9ec1-ca67ab37d3f3.png"
        ],
        "red" : [ 
            "/file/c36a3297-11bb-4028-8cb7-d750b98145ec.png", 
            "/file/4a6ec1ed-c3b1-48f9-8cb7-61dd0f6da07a.png", 
            "/file/c66ac97a-18be-4e79-8cb7-ca67ab37d3c3.png"
        ]
    }
}
```

Even though I want to save the data with the structure as shown below

```
"assets" : {
    "part 1" : {
        "black" :"/file/a11c553f-de74-48e2-93a0-6fc72a54fa9b.png",
        "red"   :"/file/a11c553f-de74-48e2-93a0-6fc72a54ga8c.png" 
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Where is your array?

Comment: @CharlieH see again my question, please help

Comment: Do you need only one element from your array?

Comment: That means you need three separate entries for three element in Black array

Comment: @CharlieH Yes I just need one element , and data black is not array but object

Comment: Please verify: You need to convert black array to black object with three properties holding those three file names?

Comment: @CharlieH I need to convert black array to black object when I push it, Is there any way for to change data saved like my achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that assets can contain many parts, here's a solution that will return the first item in each colour array:

```
var result = _.mapObject(assets, function(asset){
    return _.mapObject(asset, _.first);
});
```

Similar to the answer I gave yesterday to the question [How to change data array to be object using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34680692/how-to-change-data-array-to-be-object-using-javascript)

```js
var assets = {
     "part 1" : {
         "black" : [ 
             "/file/c36a3297-11bb-4028-8cb7-d750b98436ec.png", 
             "/file/4a6ec1ed-c3b1-48f9-84c0-61dd0f6da08a.png", 
             "/file/c66ac97a-18be-4e79-9ec1-ca67ab37d3f3.png"
         ],
         "red" : [ 
             "/file/c36a3297-11bb-4028-8cb7-d750b98145ec.png", 
             "/file/4a6ec1ed-c3b1-48f9-8cb7-61dd0f6da07a.png", 
             "/file/c66ac97a-18be-4e79-8cb7-ca67ab37d3c3.png"
         ]
     }
 }

var result = _.mapObject(assets, function(asset){
 return _.mapObject(asset, _.first);
});

document.getElementById('results').textContent = JSON.stringify(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.2/underscore.js"></script>

<pre id="results"></pre>
```

Comment: I've used this way, but the stored data does not match with my achieve, is there any way?

Comment: I can't work out from your snippet what you are trying to do - it doesn't run. Try pasting your assets object into the code snippet in my answer and see what the result looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function you can create an object out of an array:

```
function arrayToObj(a) {

   //Create an empty object
   var obj = {};

   //Go through the array and add elements as properties to the object
   a.forEach(function(element, idx){
      obj[String(idx)] = element;       
   }) 

   return obj;

}
```

This function turns `['apple', 'orange', 'grapes']` array to `{1: 'apple', 2: 'orange', 3: 'grapes'}`

And if it is that you need an object which has a single property that contains all the elements of the array as a string, here is how you do it:

```
function arrayToObjWithOneProperty(a) {

       //Create an empty object
       var obj = {value: ''};

       //Go through the array and add elements as properties to the object
       a.forEach(function(element){
          obj.value = obj.value + element + ',';       
       }) 

       return obj;

}
```

This function will convert `['apple', 'orange', 'grapes']` to `{value: 'apple,orange,grapes'}`

Comment: So how function to turn just only apple and data in array to be string?

Comment: Please rephrase your question. I can't understand it by grammar.

Comment: ok I was edit my question, beforely I'll say thanks for your help

Comment: I have already provided the code which can do what you want. You should be able to change this simple code to suite your requirement as a programmer.